# Join in an IF Statement of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Lets say we have a tableaa and want to do a Inner Join on it

```
SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b on a.x = b.y
```

In some cases a.z has a special value, then no Join should run. With an IF Statement, but how?

```
 SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y FROM tablea a
IF (a.z. <> 'special value') THEN INNER JOIN tableb b on a.x = b.y
ELSE LEFT JOIN tableb b on a.x = b.y
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2):

Add an additional condition:

```
SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y 
FROM tablea a
  INNER JOIN tableb b on a.x = b.y  AND a.z <> 'special value'
```

Note that this would also remove those rows from the result completely. If you still want to get those rows from tablea, you would need an outer join:

```
SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y 
FROM tablea a
  LEFT JOIN tableb b on a.x = b.y  AND a.z <> 'special value'
```

That will return **all** rows from tablea and only the matching ones from tableb for the rows in tablea where `z` does not have that special value

Or maybe you are looking for a UNION?

```
SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y 
FROM tablea a
  JOIN tableb b on a.x = b.y  
WHERE a.z <> 'special value'

UNION ALL 

SELECT a.x, a.z, null
FROM tablea a
WHERE a.z = 'special value'
```

Comment: Thats not working! If a.z has the special value the row will be lost, due to the inner join

Comment: @Dalitos: that's why I added the solution with the outer join.

Comment: At least he should do a LEFT JOIN, but just if a.z has the special value

Comment: I want to delete some rows, thats why i need to use the INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN is not working for me

Comment: @Dalitos: sorry, you lost me now. What does DELETE have to do with this?

Comment: ok, sorry, i will edit my question with an better code example

Answer (score 2):

In the ON clause check if `a.z = 'special value'` like this:

```
SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y 
FROM tablea a INNER JOIN b
ON a.z = 'special value' OR a.x = b.y
```

or with a conditional join:

```
SELECT a.x, a.z, b.y 
FROM tablea a LEFT JOIN b
ON 1 = CASE 
  WHEN a.z = 'special value' THEN 0 
  WHEN a.x = b.y THEN 1
END
WHERE a.z = 'special value' OR a.x = b.y
```